# Show if $|f'(x)|≤M$ then $f(x)-f(y)≤M|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $|f'(x)|≤M$ for all $x$ then $f(x)-f(y)≤M|x-y|$ for all $x,y$. Fix $y$. We have $\lim_{x \to y} |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|≤M$ so $|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|\in (M-\epsilon,M+\epsilon)$ in a neighbourhood of $y$. This is not much progress since the quotient can be greater than $M$ and I only consider a neighbourhood. Should I use something about continuity?

Comment: Try and invoke the Mean Value Theorem

Comment: Right, for any $c$, $|f(x)-f(y)=|f'(c)||x-y|≤M|x-y|$?

Comment: Not that it matters anymore since you now have a much easier approach, but if $\lim_{x \to y} \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|≤M$ then $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|$ is in $[0,M+\epsilon)$ for suitable $x$, not $(M-\epsilon,M+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $x, y$. Then the application of the Mean Value Theorem implies that there exists $c \in (x,y)$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y||f'(c)| \leq M|x-y|$.